# Access Modifiers on methods obtained from Interfaces

Tags: java

```
   interface ursus
{


 public void eat();

}

class grizzly implements ursus
{

 public void eat() //Line 1
 {

  System.out.println("Grizzly  eats Salmon ");
 }

}

class polar implements ursus
{

 public void eat() //Line 2
 {
   System.out.println("Polar eats seals ");
 }

}

class ursus_test
{

 public static void main(String args[])
 {

  grizzly g = new grizzly();
  polar p = new polar();
  p.eat();
  g.eat();

 }

}
```

When I remove the access modifier "public" from Line1/Line 2, the compiler complains that I am applying weaker access privileges for the methods "eat()" obtained from the ursus interface.

Does it mean that all methods obtained from interfaces should be only "public" on the classes which implement that interface ?

Comment: All methods in interfaces *have* to be public, whether you want them to be or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html)

The public access specifier in the interface indicates that the interface can be used by any class in any package. If you do not specify that the interface is public, your interface will be accessible only to classes defined in the same package as the interface.

All methods declared in an interface are implicitly public, so the public modifier can be omitted. If you explicitly try to add other access modifier then compiler will complaint.

Answer (score 1):

Methods declared in an interface are by default `public`. That's why the compiler is complaining. You cannot inherit a public method and then make it `protected` or `private`.

Yes, you are right on your assumption. All of the methods that you inherit from an interface should be made public.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reduce the visibility of any method.
In an interface all methods are `public` by default, so you can't make it `default access modifier` which is lesser visibility.

Answer (score 1):

When we define a method signature in `interface` it is implicitly `public` and `abstract`. `public` give visibility to that method to every `class` which are going to implement by that `interface`. So according to the presidency you should use public to inherit those method in class.

presidency of access modifiers as follows. `public>protected>default(no access modifier)> private.`